# Difference between is_published and is_merge_published in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

What is the difference between the columns is_published and is_merge_published in Sql Server  ?

I can't find docs describing it !

```
SELECT [name],[is_published],[is_merge_published] FROM sys.databases ;
```

Comment: are you referring to the system tables where is_published(sys.objects) and is_merge_published(sys.tables)

Comment: yes sys.database

Comment: well its documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, you are referring to the columns in `sys.databases`

As per [SQL Server Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> is_published  bit
>
> 1 = Database is a publication database in a
>   transactional or snapshot replication topology
>
> 0 = Is not a publication database
>
> is_merge_published    bit
>
> 1 = Database is a publication database in a
>   merge replication topology
>
> 0 = Is not a publication database in a
>   merge replication topology